# Function ereg() is deprecated

Tags: php, regex

I have started to learn PHP. So installed WAMP server on my windows 7 machine. I am trying the following PHP code :

```
<?php
$phrase = "I love PHP";
if (ereg("PHP", $phrase)) {
  echo "The expression matches";
}
?>
```

When tried this in my mozilla, I got the output :

```
Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\learnphp\common.php on line 3
The expression matches
```

I think the code is correct. I can't understand the error. Can anybody explain me what this "Deprecated" means here? and how to solve this error?

My php version is 5.3.0. can it be version problem?

EDIT : I googled it and found something about include\file.inc file in www folder. I don't have include directory in my www folder.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"Deprecated" means that PHP 5.3.0 no longer supports that function.

You should treat [ereg()](https://secure.php.net/ereg) as not existing anymore.

The function does still exist, but only to support existing applications where it's been used.

When writing new code, never use a deprecated function.

Instead, consider the [preg_match](https://secure.php.net/preg_match) function.

Answer (score 7):

Deprecated means this function will eventually be removed from PHP in a future version. You should no longer rely on it in your code and instead use the suggested alternative.

In case of PHP's [`ereg`, heed the notice in the PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php):

> As of PHP 5.3.0, the regex extension is deprecated in favor of the PCRE extension. Calling this function will issue an E_DEPRECATED notice. See the [list of differences](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php) for help on converting to PCRE.

Also see the description of [`E_DEPRECATED`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) in the PHP Manual.
For all deprecated features in PHP5.3, see [Deprecated features in PHP 5.3.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php).
For more general information see the [Wikipedia article on Deprecation in Software](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Deprecation)

Comment: This also implies that the tutorial you are learning from is hideously out of date and you should find a modern one.

Answer (score -2):

It means that the function you are using is now obsolete. You cannot use this function any more. I received the same error with PHP 5.5.6. One possible solution to your issue could be to downgrade your PHP version so it gets supported.